# How to overlay icons?

Tags: android

Those icons you can find in the sdk/platforms/data/res/drawable-hdpi... such as ic_delete. How would you go about overlaying one of those icons on a .png, using drawables?

Comment: in my app, i have some drawables that I would like to put those icons on using a drawables.xml if possible

Comment: You mean replace standard drawables or modify adding overlaying png to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place different shapes in one single layer list. In this example below, your custom drawable will be drawn on top of the android drawable ic_custom.png

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/layer_delete">
    <bitmap android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" android:gravity="center" />
  </item>
  <item android:id="@+id/layer_custom">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_custom" android:gravity="center" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```